# Is it possible that after git rebase with the master branch, some commits disappeared?

Tags: git, debugging, github, branch, git-rebase

Edited: Thanks for the feedback/ comments from users named *Romain* and *Useless*

It's indeed the inconsistency between local and remote versions of the branch. THANK YOU

---

### Context:

- I rebased `origin/featureA` branch with `origin/master` branch
- rebase was successful but some commits in `origin/featureA` disappeared?
- Please note that I didn't squash the commits, and when I said 'disappeared', I mean that **some** changes I've made in the `origin/featureA` branch were gone!
- Please note that **I'm the only one** working on `origin/featureA` branch

### Questions:

1. Has anyone here experienced this before?
2. What's the best practices here? How do you solve it when you messed up git rebase?

Comment: Note regarding "I rebased origin/featureA branch with origin/master branch" : you can't rebase a remote-tracking branch, just local ones. But if you *do* attempt it, git will dereference the remote-tracking branch to the commit it points to and rebase *that*.

Comment: You *might* not have pushed every commit on your local version of `featureA`, and if so, `origin/featureA` lacks some commits you have locally. It *could* explain your odd results. Then again, check local and remote versions of the branch to investigate this.

Comment: Finally, a lot in your question is superfluous to the comprehension, and belongs more in a discussion forum than here on SO ;-) No big offense, but a bit of trimming the chatty parts would be an improvement.

Comment: When you say _I rebased X with Y_ - I don't really know exactly what you did. We're not having a nice chat about using git and handwaving the details - you're asking for a specific solution to a specific problem and need to say exactly what you did. Paste the command line, it's in your history.

Comment: This *can* happen. It's pretty rare. To see—and thus explain—why it happened, we'd need access to your repository and the exact sequence of commands used.